# MVC - Controller - Action - Friendly URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i am searching the net non-stop.
Can pls someonw point me in the rigth direction?
My Problem:

Normally mvc display: {Controller}/{Action}
and it gives us => Home/Index

What i want: 
I want different URL without changing action or controller name like =>
MyPage/MyIndex

Should i be looking into the routing or is there an other way.

Comment: so, by default(http://localhost:portnumber) should display MyIndex view?

Comment: i am sorry if i am not clear. An other example
Home/About => MyPage/MyAbout

The landing page may display the localhost:protnumber.

Comment: check the answer..

Comment: The orginal URL: Home/About  
The wanted URL: MyPage/MyAbout

Comment: so, on the browser url will be /MyPage/MyAbout and he must be navigated to About view right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomRoute",
            url: "MyPage/MyAbout",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About"}
        );
```

Comment: Thank you mate, i appreciate your fast answer.

Comment: No probs:) Happy coding!